# How to write alter migration to add composite key in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4, migration

I am new in laravel.  I want same user can not get again same role. from postman when i am assigning role 1 to user 1, and then next time when i am again assigning role 1 to user 1, it should not happen. I have role_user table in which 3 columns are there. `id`, `role_id`, `user_id`. I want to have a composite key for `role_id`, `user_id`. But how can I write this I don't know.

```
 public function up()
 {
    Schema::table('role_users', function (Blueprint $table) {
       //     
    });
 }
```

Comment: You can use [tag:spatie]'s laravel-permission for create Role, https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission

Comment: @sta i want to just make composite key for both column. how can i do that?

Comment: you mean composite unique constraint?

Comment: @OMR yes, i want same user can not get again same role. from postman when i am assigning role 1 to user 1, and then next time when i am again assigning role 1 to user 1, it should not happen.

Answer (score 1):

this migration to update the original one, set unique constraint on more than one column:

```
 public function up()
 {
    Schema::table('role_users', function (Blueprint $table) {
          $table->unique(array('role_id', 'user_id'));
    });
 }
```

Comment: is this for alter migration or main migration file?

Comment: this for alter migration, and if you can remigrate your migration, you can add : $table->unique(array('role_id', 'user_id')); to your original one

Comment: for user should not assign again same role, is making both role_id, user_id composite key or id,role_id ? can you suggest me please

Comment: for user should not assign again same role, you should make both columns unique, so if the 1,1 comes again in insert or update operation, db will throw a violation index error

Comment: "you should make both columns unique" which column?

Comment: role_id, user_id

Comment: this constraint apply to both of them together , not only one, so for example :user_id can take 1 more than one time, but with role_id of value: 1, only one time can be existed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221249/discussion-between-aashu1807-and-omr).